# How to send triggered emails from SOAP API in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, soap-api, soap

I try to send an email from Marketing Cloud with the SOAP API but it doesn't work.
I try with SOAP UI, I always get a "OK" status but I never receive the email.

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
     <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Create</a:Action>
     <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7e0cca04-57bd-4481-864c-6ea8039d2ea0</a:MessageID>
     <a:ReplyTo>
        <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
     </a:ReplyTo>
     <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://*******.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
     <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <UsernameToken>
         <Username>USERNAME</Username>
         <Password>PASWORD</Password>
     </UsernameToken>
 </Security>
  </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Objects xsi:type="TriggeredSend">
      <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
      <TriggeredSendDefinition>
       <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
       <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
       <CustomerKey>SamDE01</CustomerKey>
      </TriggeredSendDefinition>
      <Subscribers>
       <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
       <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
       <EmailAddress>EMAILADDRESS</EmailAddress>
       <SubscriberKey>EMAILADDRESS</SubscriberKey>
       <Attributes>
         <Name>HTML__BODY</Name>
         <Value>Hello you</Value>
       </Attributes>
      </Subscribers>
    </Objects>
   </CreateRequest>
    </s:Body> 
</s:Envelope>
```

What is wrong please?

Regards

Comment: What's the status of your [triggered send interaction](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_start_a_message_interaction.htm&type=5)? Running? Paused?

Comment: I recommend making a sync call as opposed to an async call to see which error is occurring    <Options>
            <RequestType>Synchronous</RequestType>
        </Options>

Comment: This is the result:
<ExecuteResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
         <RequestID>6****-****-****-***</RequestID>
      </ExecuteResponseMsg>

If I test when I add the synchronous option (tested by adding the code at different place), I always get the overallstatus OK.

Comment: I use SOAP UI to test my quesries.
I changed the used method (from perform to create) and now , I get the error "Invalid Customer Key".

But I don't understand why because I use the customer key that I filled to create my data extension.

Comment: Have you checked to see if your Trigger is erroring on processing? The call may be successful, but there is an AMPscript syntax error or something. You could verify this either via Error count in tracking or by trying to do a send preview on the email using the Trigger Data Extension.